# getSubscription returns a null subscription

Tags: javascript, service-worker, push-api

I am new to service workers and GAE, I am able to register the service workers but not able to subscribe the PushManager, getting subscription null error. 
Find the below code for reference.

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()  
  .then(function(subscription) {  
    var pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-button');  
    pushButton.disabled = false;

    if (!subscription) {  
      console.log('subscription error '); 
      return;  
    }
    console.log('subscriptioned ');

    // Keep your server in sync with the latest subscriptionId
    sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);

    // Set your UI to show they have subscribed for  
    // push messages  
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messages';  
    isPushEnabled = true;  
  })  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.warn('Error during getSubscription()', err);  
  });
});
```

In above code getting "subscription" value as "null" inside then, so that, control is coming to if block and simply returning.

Answer (score 8):

Initially, when the user isn't subscribed, the promise returned by `getSubscription` resolves to `null`. You need to call `registration.pushManager.subscribe` in order to subscribe the user (and then, the next time the user visits your site, `getSubscription` will resolve with a non-null subscription).

There are many examples on the [ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple.html).

A simple example here:

```
// Use the PushManager to get the user's subscription to the push service.
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
.then(function(subscription) {
  // If a subscription was found, return it.
  if (subscription) {
    return subscription;
  }

  // Otherwise, subscribe the user (userVisibleOnly allows to specify
  // that we don't plan to send notifications that don't have a
  // visible effect for the user).
  return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true
  });
})
.then(function(subscription) {
  // Here you can use the subscription.
```

Comment: You can simplify this to `registration.pushManager.subscribe(...).then(subscription => ...)`. `subscribe()` will return the existing subscription if there is one, so calling `getSubscription()` first isn't necessary.

Comment: That's useful in this case, although sometimes you might need to act differently if a subscription already exists.

Comment: thanks Jeff Posnick, After making above changes, Every thing is working in local host now. But when deployed in GAE, I am getting the below error "Registration failed - no sender id provided"

Comment: You need to create a project on the Google Developer Console, get a few keys from there (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-04) and then you need to create a web app manifest containing the `gcm_sender_id` value, which is the Project Number from the Developer Console. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#Extra_steps_for_Chrome_support.